# Javascript Countdown shows NaN in IE and Firefox, works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, countdown

I'm working on a site for a client where he needs a countdown timer to count down to 10pm two days from each site update. (or however many days he wishes to enter) The countdown functions perfectly in Google Chrome but in Internet Explorer and Firefox it shows NaN NaN. I've read this means "not a number" so is there something wrong with the way my code in calculating the date information? Any help would be appreciated! My code is below:

```
<span id="countdown1" class="countdown"></span>
     <script language="javascript">

     // set the date we're counting down to 2 days from now at 10pm
var target_date1 = Date.parse("2014-01-05 22:00:00:000");

// variables for time units
var days1, hours1, minutes1, seconds1;

// get tag element
var countdown1 = document.getElementById("countdown1");

// update the tag with id "countdown" every 1 second
setInterval(function () {

// find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
var current_date1 = new Date().getTime();
var seconds_left1 = (target_date1 - current_date1) / 1000;

// do some time calculations
days1 = parseInt(seconds_left1 / 86400);
seconds_left1 = seconds_left1 % 86400;

hours1 = parseInt(seconds_left1 / 3600);
seconds_left1 = seconds_left1 % 3600;

minutes1 = parseInt(seconds_left1 / 60);
seconds1 = parseInt(seconds_left1 % 60);

// format countdown string + set tag value
countdown1.innerHTML = days1 + " days, " + hours1 + " hours, "
+ minutes1 + " minutes, " + seconds1 + " seconds";  

}, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: What debugging have you done so far? Have you `console.log()`'d your values? If you've never done so, then take a moment and find the developer tools built into your browser. They're extremely helpful for debugging.

Comment: Ok I'll take a look at that, I'm still a beginner at Javascript so no promises I'll know what I'm looking for. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: There are other services as well like http://jshint.com that are very useful to find certain bugs and errors, but I don't know if that would help in this case.

Comment: This [chrome developer tools video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOEw9iiopwI) will get you started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your date format won't work in Firefox (and apparently IE). This:

```
Date.parse("2014-01-05 22:00:00:000")
```

is `NaN` in Firefox. Firefox likes dates like `"Dec 31, 2013"` or ISO dates like `"2011-10-10T14:48:00"`. [More information at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

Comment: Thank you!! I had tried that same parsing method before but apparently if you add milliseconds "2014-01-05T22:00:00:000" it doesn't work but "2014-01-05T22:00:00" does the trick. THANK YOU!!

Comment: Actually the above method I found produced different calculations depending on which browser. This method worked better (found at link you provided)
Date.parse("Sun, 5 Jan 2014 22:30:00 EST");

Answer (score 3):

Use a RFC2822 or ISO 8601 date format for what you pass to Date.parse()
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Answer (score 0):

check this out you might like it as a count down.. wrote is yesterday:

http://jsfiddle.net/sf7Fc/
It will put your count down in a selector. you could change the way the time appear.

```
countDown($('#selector'), 300);
<div id="selector"></div>
```